# Is there any way to render svg not rectangular?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Please see this image for clarity [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgA6g.png

I use svgs for painting in a web page. The problem is they are rendering as rectangle and making an unwanted common area witch makes the coloring difficult. I want them without the empty space around them. For example in the example above the whole blue section is clickable witch makes part of the other svg unreachable.

```
import SVG from 'react-inlinesvg';

<div
              key={object.id}
              className="click-object"
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                left: `${object.x}%`,
                top: `${object.y}%`,
                width: `${object.width}%`,
                objectFit: 'contain',
                zIndex: '8',
                padding: 0,
              }}
            >
                 <SVG
                  src={object.image}
                  style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    objectFit: 'contain',
                    color:
                      selectedColor
                        ? selectedColor
                        : object.initial_color,
                  }}

                  onClick={() => setSelectedColor(object.color)}
                />
</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean.  Please annotate your screen shot so we can tell what your issue is.

Comment: I added some details on the text and picture could you see if it is clearer now? @PaulLeBeau

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be adding a click handler to the `<svg>` element. The `<svg>` element has a rectangular shape.  Any clicks within that rectangle, will be captured by that click handler.

Is there a reason why you have one SVG for each rainbow band, and stack them on top of one another?  It seems an odd way to do it.

If you want clicks to be limited to the band, then apply the click handler to the `<path>` element that forms the band.

You will also find it **much** easier if you merge all the band  `<path>` into one SVG.

Comment: thanks this seems like a solution. but when I do this in react I got an error. I explained it in another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058213/unable-to-add-onclick-to-svg-path-in-react-functional-component

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the blue square for the dev tool now it's can't be change it will be always
rectangular or square it just the area it takes of your screen all the thing inside this blue rectangle can be any shape you want in svg.
for example: circle will still have blue square around them

Comment: I added some details on the text and picture could you see if it is clearer now?